# Get the Thumbnail URL for the Multiple Zones of the SharePoint Website

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

I have a SPList Item with GUID of "212E3462-B24C-4F84-8CA0-3A703C492B8E". This is news item which has some images with thumbnails. I have multiple zones enabled for my site with AAM. I am trying to get the Thumbnail URLs for different zones. I am always getting only one default site domain name in the Thumbnail URL. Here is the code snippet. Please let me know what is the problem with my code.

```
        public NewsItem(SPListItem item)
    {
        // Get item details
        this.Title = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title].ToString();
        this.StartDate = (DateTime)item[new Guid(Fields.StartDateFieldId)];
        this.EndDate = (DateTime)item[new Guid(Fields.EndDateFieldId)];
        this.ContentType = item.ContentType.Name;
        this.Headline = item[new Guid(Fields.HeadlineFieldId)].ToString();
        this.NewsBody = item[new Guid(Fields.MainBody)].ToString();
        this.Location = SPHelper.GetTaxonomyFieldValue(item, new Guid(Fields.Location), ", ");
        this.CategoryList = SPHelper.GetTaxonomyFieldValuesList(item, new Guid(Fields.NewsCategory));
        this.TagList = SPHelper.GetTaxonomyFieldValuesList(item, new Guid(Fields.Tags));
        this.Type = item.ContentTypeId.ToString().StartsWith(ContentTypes.NewsBase_ID, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? NewsType.News : NewsType.Events;
        Logger logger = CustomLogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        logger.OpenLogFile();                   
        // Construct the URLs needed
        this.MoreUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}?lstId={2}&itmId={3}&m={4}&y={5}&ct={6}",
                                //item.ParentList.ParentWeb.Url,
                                item.ParentList.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl,                                                                       
                                ((Type == NewsType.News) ? PageConstants.NewsDetailPage_Url : PageConstants.EventDetailPage_Url),
                                item.ParentList.ID,
                                item.ID,
                                StartDate.Month,
                                StartDate.Year,
                                ContentType);            
        this.ArchiveBrowserUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}?m={2}&y={3}&ct={4}",                                    
                                item.ParentList.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, 
                                ((Type == NewsType.News) ? PageConstants.NewsTimelinePage_Url : PageConstants.EventsTimelinePage_Url),
                                StartDate.Month,
                                StartDate.Year,
                                ContentType);                      
        // Get the image - if missing get 'no image'
        if (item[new Guid(Fields.ThumbnailFieldId)] != null)
        {
            SPFieldUrlValue thumbnail = new SPFieldUrlValue(item[new Guid(Fields.ThumbnailFieldId)].ToString());
            this.ThumbnailUrl = thumbnail.Url;
            logger.Info("Guid - " + Fields.ThumbnailFieldId);
            logger.Info(" this.ThumbnailUrl - " + this.ThumbnailUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            this.ThumbnailUrl = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(item.ParentList.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, CommonConstants.Default_Img_Url);                
        }                      
    }
```

Comment: Could some one help me wiht this please?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://moriokumagawa.blogspot.nl/2013/02/alternate-access-mappings-and.html

SPFieldUrlValue from codebehind results in URL's in default zone.